# How to convert WordPress comments to bbPress replies

Tags: comments, bbpress, forum

I have a old blog that I would like to upgrade to a blog/website with bbPress forums and would like to convert the post to topics and the comments to replies. I already created my topics and now I only need to convert the comments into replies. 
Do you know of a script that does that? Have you ever had to do that and how did you do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a way. First convert posts to topics and comments to replies with [Wordpress-to-bbpress-converter](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-to-bbpress-converter/). This script is designed for BBpress 1: so you have to install first BBPress 1 and then use the script.

After that you could use the official BBPress importer (from BBPress 1 to BBPress 2)  located in Tools -> Forums -> Import Forums in the Wordpress dashboard.

At the end, remember to uninstall BBPress 1.1.